# how-to: recover a dead hard drive using Time Machine

Tags: time-machine

Not a question per se, but an observation, and hopefully someone can explain. Here's what happened (El Cap on a 2008 Mac Pro):

500 GB hard drive (not the boot drive) died, could not recover with Disk Utility. Beside the point, but the dead drive only appeared in Disk Utility after a cold boot (repair, and erase, failed); a simple restart would "hide" the drive from all probes that I could tell.

I had a backup of the drive so no worries, and the old drive has been sitting the computer for maybe 6 months, bc I was too lazy to take it out.

Fast forward... I just installed an SSD this weekend and restored my boot drive to it (still too lazy to take the failed drive out!). First thing upon reboot, I had to make sure Time Machine was working, so I confirmed this and let it proceed to back up. The TM disk is 1TB. I come back later and see a message that there was not enough space on the TM drive to complete the backup of the SSD, which is also 1TB but was only about 2/3 full. That made no sense so I opened up Backups.backupd to see what was going on, and lo and behold, there was a perfect backup of the long-failed 500 GB drive. Since there was no way for me to exclude a drive that the OS could not see, it was automatically picked up by TM after I installed the SSD, and since the failed drive was pretty full and TM chose to do it first, TM couldn't then fully back up the SSD, hence the warning message.

So... wtf: how did this even happen? How is it that TM just mounted (?) the bad drive right up and copied everything off of it?!?!? (AFAICT, everything is there and intact). Does TM have top-secret mounting skilz and/or just did a dd or something?

I've never seen anything like this before, but I'm going to add it to my list of things to try when recovering a hard drive. Hopefully someone else will see this and it will help them.

Comment: Just a suggestion: You should always have a backup drive larger than the source drive, for incremental backups. Otherwise, there's really no point in incremental backups in the first place, because you won't be able to keep much history if the source drive starts to reach capacity.

Comment: Are you sure the backup a) doesn't simply predate the failure, & b) that TM considers the new boot a different drive to the old boot & has therefore duplicated the data?

Comment: Just to clarify, the point that William T Froggard brought up was in full force. I agree that all Time Machine users should implement this strategy.

Comment: Tetsujin: yes I'm sure. The failed drive had been backed up by a method completely independent of TM (for the reasons William F pointed out). I had long since concluded that the failed drive could not be recovered. The failed drive and its backup have never been part of my TM backup strategy. AFAICT, the only reason it appeared is because of TM's inclusive protocol: unless you exclude something, it will back it up. When the new SSD went in, TM decided it could back up the failed drive. Even now, after this inadvertent recovery via TM, the failed drive cannot be mounted or repaired.

Comment: Just to clear up a possible discrepancy: originally, the failed drive was excluded from the TM backup because I used a different strategy to back it up. When it failed, it disappeared from all known mount points (in TM, DiskUtil, etc). When the new SSD was installed, the mount point for the failed drive in the TM exclusion list was long gone, which caused it to be newly backed up. This is my only theory, but as per the original point of the post, I have no idea how this could actually happen.